# Java SMTPS untrusted certificate

Tags: java, email, sendmail, smtps

When sending mail with SMTPS, I am setting the following property, so I am expecting certificate validation to be skipped. But my untrusted certificate is causing an exception.

```
mailConf.put("mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
```

The exception is:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight error in your property name. It should be `mail.smtp.ssl...` not `mail.smtps.ssl...`. Notice that it is `smtp` not `smtps`.

Answer (score 0):

Um, Looking through the docs, I have to wonder if you have made a typo. I can't find mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity, but I can find mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity.

Comment: I think it should be `mail.smtp.ssl.trust=*`. `checkserveridentity` means that the server name (the one the socket connects to) must match the certificate's subject.

My understanding is OP wants to inactivate trust verification for certain certificates. See http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html